# How do I boot from my live USB when I get a secure boot error?

Tags: secure-boot

Why is this happening and how do I get around it.[image]

I installed an ubuntu live cd image onto my USB and now whenever I try to boot from the USB I get that error.

Comment: can you disable secure boot in the BIOS setup/UEFI settings?

Comment: The thing is this only happened when I created a liveUSB when working in Ubuntu. When I created a liveUSB in Mac OS X, everything worked fine.

Comment: And I shouldn't have to disable Secure boot to get this to work...